# collectcode=TRUE will not work for me in Statamarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, stata

I'm trying to write an .rmd and eventually bookdown document with stata code. I've installed Statamarkdown and can successfully run one chunk of code. However, when I try to use the collectcode=TRUE option, I get nothing as a result in the next stata chunk:

```
     running: /Applications/Stata/StataBE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataBE  -q -e do          '/Users/myname/Documents/Work_Research/Regression_Labs/stata11f393a68b114.do' 
     
      stata output from chunk second-Stata
     r(111);

     end of do-file
     r(111);
```

I'm just trying to get the vignettes for Statamarkdown to run correctly at this point. Eventually I'm going to want to load a non-system dataset that I can use across chunks. Here's my code:

````
     ---
     title: "Basic Use of Statamarkdown"
     author: "Doug Hemken"
     date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%b %Y')`"
     output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
     
     ---
     
     This discussion assumes you already have a basic understanding
     of Markdown for document formatting, Rmarkdown to include executable
     code in a document, and Stata to write the code.
     
     ## First attach the `Statamarkdown` library
     Your first code chunk will look something like this:
     
         ```{r library}`r ''`
         library(Statamarkdown)
         ```
         
     This will either report that Stata was found, or
     that you need to specify it\'s location yourself.
     ```{r library}
     library(Statamarkdown)
     ```
     
     You can hide all of this so it does not appear in your
     final document by using the `include=FALSE`
     chunk options.
     
     ## If Stata was not found
     You will need to specify this yourself, as additional lines in
     the \"library\" code block above.
     ```{r stataexe, eval=FALSE}
     stataexe <- "/Applications/Stata/StataBE.app/Contents/MacOS/StataBE" # Mac OS
     knitr::opts_chunk$set(engine.path = list(stata = stataexe))
     ```
     
     If you do not know where to find you Stata executable (app),
     open Stata and issue the command `sysdir`.  The line labeled 
     `STATA: ` is the folder where your Stata executable is located. 
     You can browse there with your computer\'s file explorer to 
     see the actual file name of the Stata executable, which varies
     by operating system, Stata version, and Stata flavor.
     
     Then make the Stata executable
     path a default chunk option.
     
     ## An Example
     In this example we calculate a new variable in a first
     code chunk.  Then in a later code chunk we also use 
     the new variable.
     
     ### First code block:
     In the first code chunk, use the `collectcode` option.
     
         ```{stata first-Stata, collectcode=TRUE}`r ''`
         sysuse auto, clear
         generate gpm = 1/mpg
         summarize price gpm
         ```
     
     Which looks like this in your document:
     ```{stata first-Stata, collectcode=TRUE}
     sysuse auto, clear
     generate gpm = 1/mpg
     summarize price gpm
     ```
     
     ### Second code block:
     Then you can use the new variable in a later code chunk.
     
         ```{stata second-Stata}`r ''`
         regress price gpm
         ```
         
     Which looks like this in your document:
     ```{stata second-Stata, collectcode=TRUE}
     regress price gpm
     ```
````

Comment: `error 111` is "invalid syntax"., which doesn't help. I guess Statalist is more likely to include  people who have used this (not me).